# Proper way to create Facebook Session for login?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

So, I have a `Dialog` with a "share" button. When the button is pressed it calls a method that shares the users information if they are already logged in to Facebook. However, if they are not logged into Facebook I would like it to first allow the user to login and then share their information. Here's my attempt to logging the user in without a `LoginButton`:

```
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(GameActivity.this);
                    StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback(){

                        @Override
                        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "CALL");
                            if (Session.getActiveSession() != null && Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "sendBrag was called");
                                sendBrag();
                            }else{
                                Log.d(TAG, "session is not opened");
                            }
                            if (exception != null){
                                Log.d(TAG, "caught exception in call method");
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    openRequest.setCallback(callback);
                    openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
                    openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
                    Session session = new Session(GameActivity.this);
                    session.openForPublish(openRequest);
                    Session.setActiveSession(session);
```

Where, `PERMISSIONS` is:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

The problem is it never logs in! I either get a `Toast` message stating "check your network connection" (even though my network connection is fine) or nothing happens. But from the logs I can tell the Session never opens up. **To sum it all up:** How do you properly login to Facebook using the `Session` class? What am I missing here? Any help, suggestions, or advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to the problem I was having from the `SessionLoginSample` located in the samples folder within the `Facebook SDK`. First, within the `onCreate` method within my activity I put the following code:

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }
```

Where `statusCallback` is:

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
```

And the `SessionStatusCallback` inner class within my activity is:

```
    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened() && session != null){
            sendBrag();
        }
    }
}//end of SessionStatusCallback class
```

Then, I created a method that handles logging into `Facebook` if the user is not already logged in:

```
    private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}//end of onClickLogin() method
```

Which I called from the "share" button. And finally, what I believe to be the most important part of the code (I believe this may be where I ran in to an error before since I did not have this in my code), is the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}//end of onActivityResult() method
```

And that's all their really is to it. Though, I don't know why it fully worked since I use the method `openForRead` instead of `openForPublish` but it seemed to work. I hope this proves to be helpful for someone stuck with the same problem I was stuck with.